# Async node.js code (using Q) not writing to standard error

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, error-handling, q

I have encountered the following problem while writing asynchronous node.js code: **errors thrown inside an async block do not print anything to the console standard error**, they just fail silently.

Here's a self-contained working example to recreate the issue, where I call a non-existing function outside and inside an async callback:

*note the lines denoted by //! comments*

```
var Q = require('Q');

function asyncFunc(){
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('resolving promise!');
        deferred.resolve('resolveMessage');
    },2000);

    return deferred.promise;
}

asyncFunc()
    .then(function (msg) {
        nonExisting(); // ! calling here puts no error on the console
        console.log('Promise.then entered, msg:',msg);
    });

//nonExisting(); // ! calling here results in referenceError correctly printed to the console
```

I'm running the code from standard windows command prompt, with the `node file.js` command. (I'm running node 0.10.32 on Windows 7)

Why is this happening, and how can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an expected behaviour.

From the [Q API Reference:](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisedoneonfulfilled-onrejected-onprogress)

> Since exceptions thrown in then callbacks are consumed and transformed
>   into rejections, exceptions at the end of the chain are easy to
>   accidentally, silently ignore.

If you want the exception to be propagated if any promise in the chain is rejected or an exception is thrown in the resolution handler, use `done`:

```
asyncFunc().done(function (msg) { nonExisting(); }); //will throw an error in the next tick
process.on('uncaughtException', console.log);
```

You can also chain it to another `then`, whose rejection handler will be executed.

```
asyncFunc()
    .then(function (msg) {
        nonExisting(); // ! calling here puts no error on the console
        console.log('Promise.then entered, msg:',msg);
    })
    .then(function noop () {}, console.log.bind(console, 'An error was thrown'));
```